# How to change the width of image using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to change the width of an image using `.innerHTML`? I am able to change the height using the following:

```
display01.innerHTML = "<img src='images/image01.png' height='450px' >";
```

but if I try setting the width it doesn't change. I have tried the code below but it doesn't work:

```
display01.innerHTML = "<img src='images/image01.png' height='450px' width='800px'>";
```

Comment: not an expert at css but, shouldnt you just try to change the height of the container instead? `display01.style.height = '450px';`

Comment: There's no problem with the code. Maybe you are calling it in a wrong way, or the width of your image is same as ```width='800px'``` so it doesn't change.